How to load a gz file for a CNN model in Python?
Been trying to test an image classification CNN model on Python 3.11.8 with VS Code as my editor. Whenever I tried to run the main.py file, it gives me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\image-classification-using-cnn-master\image-classification-using-cnn-master\main2.py", line 16, in <module>

(training_images, training_labels), (testing_images, testing_lables) = unpickle(local_dataset_path)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "c:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\image-classification-using-cnn-master\image-classification-using-cnn-master\main2.py", line 11, in unpickle

dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'.

This is what my code looks like:
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import tensorflow
import pickle
from keras._tf_keras.keras import models, layers, datasets


def unpickle(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict

local_dataset_path = 'cifar-10-python.tar.gz'

(training_images, training_labels), (testing_images, testing_lables) = unpickle(local_dataset_path)

The gz file ('cifar-10-python.tar.gz') is located in the same folder as main.py is.
How to resolve this issue?

local_dataset_path = 'cifar-10-python.tar.gz' is not a pickle file that is why you cannot unpickle it. you need to extract the .tar.gz file first;... import tarfile module in Python. read the documentation for this module: Python tarfile module documentation.

I did some working and I was wondering if including these would work either way:
def load_cifar10_batch(dataset_dir, batch_name):
file_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, batch_name)
batch = unpickle(file_path)
return batch[b'data'], batch[b'labels']

If you extracted the tar.gz file... Just note that your unpickle() function only works with pickle files...  haven't tested it out... lmk if it works...
